# VMWare vSphere Web Client loading forever

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I'm currently learning about VMware virtualization technology and setup a small lab. However, the freshly installed vSphere Client (VMware vCenter Server Appliance, flash version) hangs on loading

[image: screenshot].

What I tried so far:

- Reboot the vSphere Client Appliance
- Tried different Browsers (Internet Explorer, Edge, Firefox, Chrome)
- Tried different OS (Windows Server 2012R2 and Windows 10)
- Reinstalled Flash

I have no idea what else could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to work it out myself.
There were several problems with my setup uf my vCenter server:

- I used the same Domainname for the SSO Domain as my AD Domain
- I logged in with simply 'root' - instead of administrator@

After I fixed those points (had to reinstall vCenter server, I don't think you can change those points after initial installation) everything worked fine :)

Regards - Christian